# Check if a string has only blank spaces or zeros with C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to detect if an `IBAN` account has all digits at `zero` `0`, for example

`00 0000 000 00 0000000000`.

So I build this regex pattern to check it:

`^(0\s){0,25}$`

The argument would be: Check if the input string has only blank spaces or zeros.

But this does not work. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: you are wanting `or` operator `^(0|\s){0,25}$` or character class `^[0\s]{0,25}$`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a non-regex example.

```
string input = "00 0000 000 00 0000000000";

bool isNotAllZeros = input
    .Where(x => char.IsDigit(x))
    .Any(x => x != '0');
```

It says: "get me all the digits from the string, and see if there are any that are not '0'."

Another method (to avoid double-negatives), using `All`, which might make more sense when reading:

```
bool isAllZeros = input
    .Where(x => char.IsDigit(x))
    .All(x => x == '0');
```

This says "are all the digits in the input '0'?"

Comment: `x => char.IsDigit(x)` is equivalent to `char.IsDigit`

Comment: @Andrey, true, but that is personal preference. I choose this format because I find it easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `or` operator `|`

```
^(0|\s){0,25}$
```

Or, you can use character class:

```
^[0\s]{0,25}$
```

### Forget the above. You can do this:

```
string input = "00 0000 000 00 0000000000";
bool isAllNum = input.IndexOf(" ") == -1; //true if all are numbers without space
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for `0` or blank spaces, add `0` and the space character to a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). If you want to match (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\f` and `' '`) then use `\s` in place.

```
^[0 ]{0,25}$
```

Answer (score 2):

A very efficient way to handle this would be:

```
string input = "00 0000 000 00 0000000000";

bool isAllZero = input.Any(i => i != ' ' && i != '0');
```

Which will stop executing at the first instance of a non space, non zero character.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this regex if you want to keep the format,

```
^[0]{2}\s[0]{4}\s[0]{3}\s[0]{2}\s[0]{10}$
```

OR

```
^0{2}\s0{4}\s0{3}\s0{2}\s0{10}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tD2gO4)

Comment: Square brackets are not necessary